# How to copy values from bit column to datetime column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012

I want to copy values from a `bit` column called "absent" in table `Person` to a new, empty `datetime` column I just made.

The `bit` type column contains rows with values null, 0 and 1.

Now, I'd like to copy the values of this `bit` column to the new `datetime` column so, that all null AND 0 values in the `bit` column would be null values in the `datetime` column. All the 1 values would be new, current dates.

How to do that? I tried to search for w3bschools for some examples but couldn't find any.

Comment: Please try a search for 'case', 'case when'. Or see this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Comment: Thank you. I had no idea of such a keyword. This is most useful. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can do it like this:

```
update Person
set dateTime_Column = case when isnull(absent, 0) = 0 then null else getdate() end
```

Comment: Two problem solving answers on the same minute. What to do?

Comment: @SteveWaters well, answers almost identical and in the same minute (while in fact mine was some seconds earlier). Just flip a coin and let it choose the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
update someTable
set dateColumn = case when bitColumn is null or bitColumn = 0 then null else getdate() end
```

Comment: Two problem solving answers on the same minute. What to do?

Comment: You can consider that @Andy Korneyev was the first, but my query will use possible index on `bitColumn`  but Andy's query wll not use that index if any exists. So it is totally up to you to choose from. No problem at all :)

Answer (score 0):

You really just need to update the rows that have bitColumn = 1 and leave the others null if you didn't use a default value when you created the new column.

```
update Person
set dateTime_Column = getdate()
where bitColumn = 1
```